# Store an LCD, without defining

Tags: c++, class, arduino, lcd

I have this class I am making:

```
class SerialLoad {
    public:
        SerialLoad(int line, int total, LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd);
        void increment();
        void print();
        void clearLine();
    private:
        int line;
        int current;
        int total;
        int percent;
        LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
};
```

And as you can see I want to pass in an LCD that will be created elsewhere, but it is giving me an error here because I cannot do "LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;" without creating a new one.  How should I go about fixing this?

What I want to do is just pass one in...

Here is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SerialLoad\SerialLoad.cpp: In constructor 'SerialLoad::SerialLoad(int, int, LiquidCrystal_I2C)':
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SerialLoad\SerialLoad.cpp:5: error: no matching function for call to 'LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C()'
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:93: note: candidates are: LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, t_backlighPol)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:89: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:70: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, t_backlighPol)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:67: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:53: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t, uint8_t, t_backlighPol)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:51: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(uint8_t)
C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\LiquidCrystal/LiquidCrystal_I2C.h:39: note:                 LiquidCrystal_I2C::LiquidCrystal_I2C(const LiquidCrystal_I2C&)
```

Comment: Use a reference or a pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not very specific to arduino but rather is a very general c++ question. 
In order to store an object that is created outside of your class, you can e.g. store a pointer to the object, so rather than having

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
```

you should have

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C *lcd;
```

In the constructor of your class you have to then change things accordingly and assign the pointer to the member of your class.

```
SerialLoad(int line, int total, LiquidCrystal_I2C *outsideLcd)
{
   lcd = outsideLcd;
}
```

Another couple of comments: 
Depending on how you create the `LiquidCrystal_I2C` object, you need to pass it differently to the class.

If you do

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd;
```

you have to do

```
SerialLoad s([other variables here], &lcd);
```

Which means that you are passing the address of the `lcd` object to your constructor. 
If you create the `LiquidCrystal_I2C` with [new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29), then you can simply do

```
SerialLoad s([other variables here], lcd);
```

One thing you have to make sure is that the `LiquidCrystal_I2C` that you create outside of your class is not destroyed before you stop using it in your class, otherwise your code will crash the moment you try to access it inside your class.

Let me know if this helps. As said at the beginning, this is not at all arduino specific but purely c++.